# How do I run chef recipe from inside ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef, ruby, chef-solo

From the Rails app I need to provision, configure and manage servers on Amazon AWS. Some time ago I've been using chef-solo and knife to do that, but from the command line. Would that be possible to do the same from inside the code? Any pointers on how to start?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [chef-zero](https://github.com/chef/chef-zero), it supersedes chef-solo as the way forward for running Chef without a central Chef Serer.  It also has the advantage of having a Ruby API so you don't have to shell out.

From the description:

> Chef Zero is a simple, easy-install, in-memory Chef server that can be useful for Chef Client testing and chef-solo-like tasks that require a full Chef Server.